# How do I tell Entity Framework that a column in a view is nullable?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a view which has an Int column which is nullable (let's call it StackOverflowCount). When generating an EF model from the database, the EF designer does not recognise it as nullable and creates the column as an Int.

The issue I have is that on the EF designer I have set the column to Nullable and the following error then kills the compilation;

```
Error 3031: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 2327:
Non-nullable column MyView.StackOverflowCount in table MyView
is mapped to a nullable entity property.
```

I can get round this by opening the .edmx file in XML mode and manually editing the SQL column definition, but there is no way to do this using the designer and it gets overwritten the next time I refresh from the model from the DB.

Is this 'by design' or an example of something that slipped through into EF 4.0? I'm using .Net 4.0 with EF 4.0 under VS 2010.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I'm running EF on VS2010 and have the same issue.

Comment: Oh yes, I needed to recreate the view. It was binding to an old definition.

Comment: Just for future reference. In my case deleting the view and remapping it didn't fix the issue `:s` but changing the column definition from `fieldName` to `NULLIF(fieldName, NULL)` did the trick. Not that it looks good, but at least it works.

Comment: NULLIF did not work for me. I had to UNION the results with all NULL columns, and then reimport the view. At that point EF recognized the columns as nullable. I think the way it works is, EF queries the view, and if a column has nulls, then it's nullable, else non-nullable. My UNION forced nulls into all the columns and tricked EF. After the import, I went into SSMS and removed the UNION from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF has a lot of functionality that is not available in the designer.

This is not so much "by design", but probably that they ran out of time.

There are several improvements in EF in VS2010, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee720194.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Select the column in the entity in model viewer, go to Properties and set Nullable to true.